# DB2: Oracle-like associative arrays?

Tags: oracle, db2

Does DB2 provide a feature similar to the associative arrays in the Oracle database server?

Comment: Take care of your capslook key. Words in capital letter means screaming and that is a no go in all forums.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow At this site you are expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing more research, if you have a problem you can post **what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. I suggest reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question and the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/6676466).

Answer (score 0):

[Db2 provides associative arrays](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/c0053499.html?pos=2). You can use them as part of the SQL Procedure Language. An example would be:

```
CREATE TYPE capitalsArray AS VARCHAR(12) ARRAY[VARCHAR(16)];
DECLARE capitals capitalsArray;

SET capitals['Germany'] = 'Berlin';
```